# string.format() not showing values

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone tell me why does this string.Format() doesn't show the 1st value?

```
long countLoop = 0;
long countTotal = 3721;

string.Format("Processed {0:#,###,###} lines of {1:#,###,###} ({2:P0})", countLoop, countTotal, ((double)countLoop / countTotal));
```

The result I got are

```
Processed  lines of 3,721 (0 %)
```

But if I replaced countTotal with a number 1

```
string.Format("Processed {0:#,###,###} lines of {1:#,###,###} ({2:P0})", 1, countTotal, ((double)countLoop / countTotal));
```

I get this

Processed 1 lines of 3,721 (0 %).

Is there something about string.Format that I don't know about?

Comment: I'm thinking that {0:#,##,###}, when passed 0 as the value, is resulting in nothing....by the way, shouldn't the third substitution be the number 2?  I.e., `{3:P0}` should be `{2:P0}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation on the [the "#" custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD):

> Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string.

If you'd like to display "0" in this case, take a look at [the "0" custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0):

> If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where the zero appears in the format string, that digit is copied to the result string; otherwise, a zero appears in the result string.

This should work for you:

```
string.Format(
    "Processed {0:#,###,##0} lines of {1:#,###,###} ({2:P0})", 
    countLoop, countTotal, ((double)countLoop / countTotal));
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your string format to

```
string.Format("Processed {0:#,###,##0} lines of {1:#,###,###} ({2:P0})", countLoop, countTotal, ((double)countLoop / countTotal));
```

this will print 0 when the countLoop is zero.

As other have said before me, the # placeholder doesn't print the zero when it is not a significant digit.

**Note** I have fixed your indexing inside the format string. 
You have only three parameters, so the index goes from 0 to 2 (not 3 as you have at the end `({3:P0})`

Comment: Do track some attention to `2:P0`